# Entering integers doesn't stop for non-integers

Tags: c

I have a program in which I enter integers until something that is not an integer is entered. The code needs to print the integers that meet the following condition:

```
integer "abcde": "a > b, b < c, c > d, d < e" or "a < b, b > c, c < d, d > e"
example: 343, 4624, 6231209
```

I have written this, and it works for most of the integers, but somehow it doesnt work for some.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    while (scanf("%d", &a))
    {
        int a1 = a;
        int cifra = 0, cifra1 = 0, cifra2 = 0;
        while (a1 > 0)
        {
            cifra = a1 % 10;
            cifra1 = (a1 / 10) % 10;
            cifra2 = (a1 / 100) % 10;
            a1 = a1 / 10;

            if (cifra == cifra1 || cifra1 == cifra2)
            {
                break;
            }

            if ((cifra < cifra1 && cifra1 > cifra2) || (cifra > cifra1 && cifra1 < cifra2)) {

                printf("%d\n", a);
                break;

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your input. For which inputs it did work, for which it didn't. I don't know what you tried or what problem you have experienced.

Comment: it worked for most, it just didnt work for 12231, 12, 6545

Comment: You only look at the last 3 digits, that's why. Note that the inner `while` loop will never go more that one iteration since you will always encounter a `break` in the `if-else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
int cifra = 0, cifra1 = 0, cifra2 = 0;
int a1;
while(scanf("%d", &a))
{


    int a1 = a;
    while(a1 > 0){
            if(a1 <= 9)
    {
        break;
    }
    cifra = a1 % 10;
    cifra1 = (a1 / 10) % 10;
    cifra2 = (a1 / 100) % 10;

    if((cifra > cifra1 || cifra1 > cifra)&&cifra2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        break;
    }

    if((cifra < cifra1&&cifra1 > cifra2) || (cifra > cifra1&&cifra1 < cifra2))
    {
        a1 = a1 / 10;;

    }
    else
    {

        break;
    }



    }



}

return 0;
}
```